# How to put image background in a variable?

Tags: php

It’s kind of a stupid question, but I need to store a `div` with a background image in a variable.  My problem arises from the use of `"` and `'`.

This is obviously wrong:

```
$var = "<div style="background-image:url('bg.png');">";
```

I have also tried these methods but none worked:

```
$var = "<div style='"."background-image:url('bg.png');".'">";

$var = "<div style='";
$var = $var."background-image:url('bg.png');";
$var = $var."'>";
```

Does anyone know how I can make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the double quotes that's messing with you. You would either have to do `\"` or just use single quotes (acceptable in PHP, and more convenient with HTML):

```
$var = '<div style="background-image:url(\'bg.png\');">';
```

With double quotes:

```
$var = "<div style=\"background-image:url('bg.png');\">";
```

This is valid and will work. Now just use `echo $var;` to show it.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use single quotes or escape double quotes to avoid any problems

```
$var = "<div style=\"background-image:url('bg.png');\">";
```

Or

```
$var = '<div style="background-image:url(\'bg.png\');">';
```

Comment: quotes around bg.png are not necessary for css to be valid, so that can be of help and less headache :)